# Check if an object is empty in Nunjucks

Tags: javascript, node.js, templating, nunjucks

So I'm using Nunjucks as the templating engine in my Node.js application.

I have an object we'll call `var` which may or may not be empty.

When it is empty, if I do
`{{ var | dump }}` Nunjucks properly shows that it is an empty object, displaying `{}`.

The problem is, I can't find any way to check if the object is empty using Nunjuck's `{% if condition %}` statement. I have tried `var.length`, `var | length`, `var | first`, and just plain `var` for the condition, but none of them work, they all just evaluate to true (or false), regardless of whether or not `var` is empty. Does anyone know how to solve this?

EDIT: using `{% if var | dump != '{}' %}` does work, but seems like a really hacky solution...

EDIT 2: I ended up just creating a custom `empty` filter for objects which does what I need:

```
env.addFilter('empty', function(object) {
    return Object.keys(object).length === 0;
});
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Support for accessing an object's length with the `length` filter was recently added in [Nunjucks 2.5.0](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/releases/tag/v2.5.0).

So you can now use:

```
{% if var|length %}
```

Comment: God bless you and your family.

But can you give some more information on how should I really "understand" that syntax? Because it makes no sense to me :)

Comment: @BBerastegui  the `length` filter returns the number of items within an object. If `var` in this case is an empty object, then it returns a length of 0. This evaluates to false therefore the `if` condition does not run. On the other hand any positive `length` would evaluate to true and the condition block would run.